# Python Read then Write project

Tags: python-2.7, encryption, encoding, decoding, read-write

I am trying to write a program that will read a text file and convert what it reads to another text file but using the given variables. Kinda like a homemade encryption. I want the program to read 2 bytes at a time and read the entire file. I am new to python but enjoy the application. any help would be greatly appreciated

a = 12
b = 34
c = 56
etc... up to 20 different types of variables

file2= open("textfile2.text","w")
file = open("testfile.txt","r") 
file.read(2):
    if file.read(2) = 12 then;
    file2.write("a")
      else if file.read(2) = 34
    file2.write("b")
      else if file.read(2) = 56
    file2.write("c")
    file.close()
    file2.close()

Text file would look like:
1234567890182555

so the program would read 12 and write "a" in the other text file and then read 34 and put "b" in the other text file. Just having some logic issues.

Comment: Your pseudo code is logically sound. You are having some major syntax issues because you did not read a basic tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like your idea here is how I would do it. Note I convert everything to lowercase using `lower()` however if you understand what I am doing it would be quite simple to extend this to work on both lower and uppercase:

```
import string

d = dict.fromkeys(string.ascii_lowercase, 0) # Create a dictionary of all the letters in the alphabet

updates = 0
while updates < 20: # Can only encode 20 characters
    letter = input("Enter a letter you want to encode or type encode to start encoding the file: ")
    if letter.lower() == "encode": # Check if the user inputed encode
        break
    if len(letter) == 1 and letter.isalpha(): # Check the users input was only 1 character long and in the alphabet
        encode = input("What do want to encode %s to: " % letter.lower()) # Ask the user what they want to encode that letter to
        d[letter.lower()] = encode
        updates += 1
    else:
        print("Please enter a letter...")

with open("data.txt") as f:
    content = list(f.read().lower())

for idx, val in enumerate(content):
    if val.isalpha():
        content[idx] = d[val]

with open("data.txt", 'w') as f:
    f.write(''.join(map(str, content)))

print("The file has been encoded!")
```

**Example Usage:**

Original data.txt:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

Running the script:

```
Enter a letter you want to encode or type encode to start encoding the file: T                                                                                                                                                                                          
What do want to encode t to: 6                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
Enter a letter you want to encode or type encode to start encoding the file: H                                                                                                                                                                                          
What do want to encode h to: 8                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
Enter a letter you want to encode or type encode to start encoding the file: u                                                                                                                                                                                          
What do want to encode u to: 92                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Enter a letter you want to encode or type encode to start encoding the file: 34                                                                                                                                                                                         
Please enter a letter...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
Enter a letter you want to encode or type encode to start encoding the file: rt                                                                                                                                                                                         
Please enter a letter...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
Enter a letter you want to encode or type encode to start encoding the file: q                                                                                                                                                                                          
What do want to encode q to: 9                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
Enter a letter you want to encode or type encode to start encoding the file: encode                                                                                                                                                                                     
The file has been encoded!
```

Encode data.txt:

```
680 992000 00000 000 092000 0000 680 0000 000
```

Comment: Will add more comments explaining what my thought process was, if anyone asks.

Answer (score 0):

I would read the source file and convert the items as you go into a string.  Then write the entire result string separately to the second file.  This would also allow you to use the better `with open` construct for file reading.  This allows python to handle file closing for you.

This code will not work because it only reads the first two characters.  you need to create your own idea on how to iterate it, but here is an idea (without just making a solution for you)

```
with open("textfile.text","r") as f:
    # you need to create a way to iterate over these two byte/char increments
    code = f.read(2)
        decoded = <figure out what code translates to>
        results += decoded

# now you have a decoded string inside `results`

with open("testfile.txt","w") as f:
    f.write(results)
```

the `decoded = <figure out what code translates to>` part can be done much better than using a bunch of serial if/elseifs....

perhaps define a dictionary of the encodings?

```
codings = {
    "12": "a",
    "45": "b",
    #  etc...
    }
```

then you could just:

```
results += codings[code]
```

instead of the if statements (and it would be faster).

Comment: Of course there are other issues, like what if you can't get two bytes; how to handle line feeds or other whitespace... This makes a nice learning exercise, but if you are actually wanting to encrypt stuff, you should be looking at doing so with REAL encryption modules and algorithms and not try to home make something like this (which would be easy for the right person to crack)